# Render multiple divs with jQuery result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some data which I need to render on a page. The form of the page would be something like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div style="border: 2px solid grey; border-radius: 12px; padding: 5px; margin-bottom: 10px" class="anliegenGrammatik"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <button class="btn"><b style="color: red">X</span></b>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is from where I get the data:

```
function selectGrammar(grammar) {
    var params = {};
    params['BereichID'] = bereichsID;
    params['GrammarName'] = grammar.text.trim();
    params = JSON.stringify(params, null, ' ');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/something&DLLFunc=getAnliegenGrammar',
        type: "POST", // type of action POST || GET
        data: params,
        dataType: 'json', // data type
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(response) {
            $('#exampleModalLong').modal('toggle');
            $('.anliegenGrammatik').text("Test");
            showPage('afterBrowse');
        },
        error: function(xhr, resp, text) {
            console.log(xhr, resp, text);
        }
    })
}
```

As `response` I have multiple items (as JSON)... And I want to render a div for each of the items.

I tried something like this:

```
$.each(response, function(index) {
    $('.anliegenGrammatik').text(response[index].name);
});
```

But it only fills and shows one div.

Anyone?

Comment: How looks your JSON response?

Comment: It contains multiple names... `name: "Something"`

Comment: Are you sure that `response` is array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you keep changing the text of the same element `.anliegenGrammatik`

Your html and loop should be like

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-md-3" id="append_target">
            <div style="border: 2px solid grey; border-radius: 12px; padding: 5px; margin-bottom: 10px" class="anliegenGrammatik"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <button class="btn"><b style="color: red">X</span></b>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

/* SCRIPT */

var clone = $('.anliegenGrammatik').clone();
$('.anliegenGrammatik').remove();
$.each(response, function(index, item) {
    var t_clone = clone.clone(); // you need to clone each loop cycle 
                                 // otherwise you keep appending the same element again and again
    t_clone.text( item.name );
    $('#append_target').append(t_clone);
});
```

Comment: My bad... I made a typo in append_target id. It works. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery `text` method overwrites the content of the element. Try to use `append` instead of `text`.

Like this:

```
$.each(response, function(index) {
    $('.anliegenGrammatik').append(response[index].name + ', ');
});
```

Comment: I don't need to append the div. I need to create a new one (div) for each element.